# Writing to a Stream using byte[] vs a ReadOnlyMemory<Byte>

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

Is there a difference between writing to a `Stream` using `byte[]`:

[await stream.WriteAsync(b, 0, b.Length, cancellationToken);](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.writeasync?view=net-6.0#System_IO_Stream_WriteAsync_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)

and between using `ReadOnlyMemory<Byte>`:

[await stream.WriteAsync(b, cancellationToken);](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.writeasync?view=net-6.0#System_IO_Stream_WriteAsync_System_ReadOnlyMemory_System_Byte__System_Threading_CancellationToken_)

(which still accepts the same `byte[]` but considers it a `ReadOnlyMemory<Byte>`.

Are there any drawbacks to using the second one (which is the one Visual Studio suggests)?

I'm not asking which is better. I'm asking if there are any drawbacks to using the second / what's the difference between the two.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/corert/blob/c6af4cfc8b625851b91823d9be746c4f7abdc667/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/IO/Stream.cs#L243

Comment: @GSerg Thanks. Just summarizing: They sacrificed resources in order to add readability in this implementation of the byte[] overload, making them the same.

Comment: The `byte[]` overload predates the `ValueTask` type. It's not that they sacrificed resources. It's that they reimplemented a long-standing overload in terms of a newer one. Yes, the `byte[]` overload does force allocation of a `Task` object, but that was always going to be the case, even before the `ReadOnlyMemory<byte>` overload, which returns `ValueTask`, was introduced.

Comment: @madreflection The `byte[]` overload, (in this implementation) creates a new instance of `ReadOnlyMemory`. That's what I was referring to.

Comment: @ispiro:  I see what you mean. Point taken.